# Can I display DNA of QWidget?

Tags: qt

I have a situation where for the first time I receive multitouch events on QDial and then I receive touch event on only on widget. For more info click [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/36164-Qt-Multi-touch-Dials-example-not-working-as-expected?highlight=)

What I want to do is get the  DNA (for lack of better word, I mean everything that might change how a widget my behave) of QWidget (so something similar) when the application starts and then get the DNA of QWidget when I have touched it once and see what has changed which leads to change in behavior.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check QWidget's window flags for any changes

Qt::WindowFlags windowFlags () const;